# Align navbar in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

Please have a look at this one : `http://83.212.101.132/betdk/home/two`

- When the user scrolls, the navbar goes to the top (using the `affix` plugin).
- However, it takes up the whole row (with "Home" going to the left).

What should I do in order for it to :

- retain the full-width blue-ish background
- the contents remain centered

---

**This is the affix-related CSS** :

```
        .affix {
            position: fixed;

            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            left:0;
            z-index:10;
            box-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
           -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
           -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
            border-radius: 0 !important;

        }

        .affix .subcon {
            /* The wrapper around the navbar contents */
        }
```

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

Unykvis' answer *does* work.

With one addition (to avoid messing up the navbar contents in its original form)

```
.navbar .container {
    padding-left:0px;padding-right:47px
}
            .navbar.affix .container {
padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `.container` div around the Menu:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main" style="padding-left:0; ">
  <div class="container">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

This is what you want, correct?

[image: This is what you want, correct?]

So do this:

[image: Solved]

**EDIT**

To fix the aliment I would do:

```
<div id="nav-fixed" class="container">
```

And change via jQuery from "container-fluid" to "container", when it is normal, it has to fluid, when it is affix it has to be container.

Comment: I've tried this one. And it *does* work for the affix. However it messes up the navbar when it is in place (NOT affixed). Any suggestions regarding this one?

Comment: I tried it in your site via console it worked. I will add an image. You need to add BOTH UL's not only one.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work. I'm saying it messes the navbar in its original form (look at the right most element. it goes beyond the border...)

Comment: You mean to include both `<ul>`s inside the `.container`? If that's what you mean, that's exactly what I did...

Comment: Have a look at this one, please : http://s1.postimg.org/drknvrjzz/Captura_de_pantalla_2014_07_01_a_la_s_02_16_27.png - "WrapBootstrap" is now beyond bounds. As fot the affix, *yes* that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Mark it as solved. I will help you with the other problem now.

Comment: Thanks. I've just managed to solve it. Have a look at my updated original post.

Comment: Do you know how to do what I edited? Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56591/discussion-between-unykvis-and-dr-kameleon).

Answer (score 0):

These following properties allow to center a fixed element :

```
width:1000px;
margin-left:-500px;
left:50%;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjahim/LxxwD/2/)